Trying to reorder and rename my data labels for ggplot in R
I'm fairly new to R and I currently can make an ok boxplot, but I'd like instead of S16 or S127 for the labels to be "#16 (auto)" and "#127 (X-linked)" and similar for the other sample labels. I'd rather not just change the label in the original file since I have plenty of stats based on the current labeling. I also want to change the order so that the data appears like S16, S19, S17, S20, S127 in the boxplot. If I could also get the dots to be a black instead of the same color as the boxes, that would be perfect!
Here's a snippet of data:



Sample
RedEx




S16
1.08


S16
0.64


S16
1.27


S17
2.07


S17
0.83


S17
0.86


S19
0.92


S19
0.99


S19
1.12


S20
0.68


S20
0.21


S20
1.31


S127
2.38


S127
4.07


S127
2.86



ratios <- read.table("qPCRSummary.csv", 
                     dec = ".",
                     sep = ",",
                     header = T,
                     stringsAsFactors = T)

ggplot(ratios, aes(x= Sample, y= RedEx, fill= Sample)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="center", dotsize=0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("aquamarine2", "lightskyblue2", "#2ecc71","#0099f8", "#e74c3c", "#2ecc71")) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(
    x = "Transgenic Line",
    y = "Average expression"
  )


I tried mutate() like this: new <- ratios %>% mutate ("#16 (auto)" = S16) but got an error saying not applicable to factors. I've searched online and I can't seem to find an example that I can follow.

If you don't want to change the data, use the labels argument of scale_fill_manual() and scale_x_discrete() to specify how you want the labels to appear.

Or probably I would do: ratios |> mutate(Sample = factor(Sample, c("S16", "S19", "S17", "S20", "S127"), c("#16 (auto)", "#19 (auto)", "#17 (auto)", "#20 (auto)", "#127 (X-linked)"))) |> ggplot(...... Use color = "black" in your geom_dotplot to make the dots black..

Thanks for answering! When I add the line ratios |> mutate(Sample = factor(Sample, c("S16", "S19", "S17", "S20", "S127"), c("#16 (auto)", "#19 (auto)", "#17 (auto)", "#20 (auto)", "#127 (X-linked)"))) |> then I get an error saying Error in ggplot() mapping should be created with aes(). But I still have that included. Also even if I put geom_dotplot after scale_fill_manual I don't get black dots with color= "black".

You have to use fill = "black" for geom_dotplot, i.e. geom_dotplot(..., fill = "black"). And most likely you get the error because you still have ratios in ggplot(), i..e check that you do .... |> ggplot(aes(...)) + ....
